# Laravel 5.6 - "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running a test in my controller just to make sure I get a output. Unfortunately, I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error. I just want to see the name field displayed as per code below.

Here's my Model (Member.php):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Here's my MemberController.php file:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $member = Member::find('$id'); 

        //Test
        echo $member->name;
        exit;

        return view('members/show', $data); 
    }
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('members/{member}', 'MemberController@show');
```

This is my schema where the table is named members and the name field is defined:
[image]

Like I said, when I run my url at Some_url/members/1 I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Change `$member = Member::find('$id'); ` to `$member = Member::find($id); `

Comment: That worked. Feel embarrassed. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$member = Member::find('$id');
```

This line is the culprit.

Change it to:

```
$member = Member::find($id);
```

Reasons should be obvious ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also don't include 'exit' before 'return'. It won't show the view if you do it like that.

Comment: I think OP was trying to do a manual `dd()`. But good call nonetheless!

Comment: It was my intention not to display any content afterwards. It was a test. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$member = Member::findOrFail($id);`
**OR**
`$member = Member::find($id);`

when you use a variable as a parameter don't use in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try-out [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding). Does it look clearer?

```
public function show(Member $member)
{
    return view('members/show', ['id' => $member->getKey()]); 
}
```